# React Native 0.64-65 with XCode 13 build error - could not find auto-linked library swift_Concurrency or swiftFileProvider

Tags: react-native, xcode13, macos-monterey

[image]

Anyone else getting this since upgrading to [XCode 13 Beta](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-13-beta-release-notes) and [macOS 12 Beta](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos-release-notes/macos-12-beta-release-notes) (Monterey)?

XCode 12.5 still builds successfully with RN 0.64.2 and 0.65.0-rc.2.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**[Update](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31733#issuecomment-904075304): Fixed in React Native [v0.66.0](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.66.0)**

> We believe this fixed it (in main): [eb93886](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/eb938863063f5535735af2be4e706f70647e5b90)

---

Another similar case [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31733)

Seems related to flipper, disabling it builds successfully for now as a temporary workaround

*Podfile*

```
...

# use_flipper!()

...
```

```sh
pod install
```

*ios/MyApp/AppDelegate.m*

```cpp
// Disable these parts for Flipper

#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
#import <FlipperKit/FlipperClient.h>
#import <FlipperKitLayoutPlugin/FlipperKitLayoutPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitUserDefaultsPlugin/FKUserDefaultsPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitNetworkPlugin/FlipperKitNetworkPlugin.h>
#import <SKIOSNetworkPlugin/SKIOSNetworkAdapter.h>
#import <FlipperKitReactPlugin/FlipperKitReactPlugin.h>
    
static void InitializeFlipper(UIApplication *application) {
  FlipperClient *client = [FlipperClient sharedClient];
  SKDescriptorMapper *layoutDescriptorMapper = [[SKDescriptorMapper alloc] initWithDefaults];
  [client addPlugin:[[FlipperKitLayoutPlugin alloc] initWithRootNode:application withDescriptorMapper:layoutDescriptorMapper]];
  [client addPlugin:[[FKUserDefaultsPlugin alloc] initWithSuiteName:nil]];
  [client addPlugin:[FlipperKitReactPlugin new]];
  [client addPlugin:[[FlipperKitNetworkPlugin alloc] initWithNetworkAdapter:[SKIOSNetworkAdapter new]]];
  [client start];
}
#endif
    
...
    
#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
  InitializeFlipper(application);
#endif
```

I've raised the issue [here](https://github.com/facebook/flipper/issues/2477)

Comment: Worked for me on react-native 0.63.4

Answer (score 11):

**Update: This works for XCode Version 13.0 (13A233), too.**

For XCode Version 12.0.1 (12A7300),

I just added **libswiftWebKit.tbd** to

***Link Binary with Libraries*** (from project, **Build Phases**)

and the build was successful.

See image below:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This was already fixed in this commit. I implemented the 2 minor changes manually and it worked for me:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/eb938863063f5535735af2be4e706f70647e5b90