# XCode 13 Build Error - Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swift_Concurrency' - React Native 0.64-65

Tags: ios, react-native, ios15, xcode13, flipper

### Preface

*This my first time answering my own question so if there's anything wrong with my explanation just leave a comment and make any necessary correction*

The following is just a updated answer for those whose XCode was automatically updated to the stable release of XCode 13 and have been running a bare React Native Project.

This issue has been seen in other questions that was posted a few months back.
One of them can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68054595/react-native-0-64-65-with-xcode-13-build-error-could-not-find-auto-linked-libr).

### The Issue

Apparently after updating to XCode 13 and trying to run my React-Native app in the simulator would apparently result in a build error with the following log

```
Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swift_Concurrency'
Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftFileProvider'
```

I'm not sure about others but you might get a similar error log that has to do with the 'auto-linked library'

Comment: if you have upgraded your mac and xcode then possible issue could be https://stackoverflow.com/a/69882460/2457493

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Resolution

So from previous questions that were posted and also from this [Github Issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31733), the build failure apparently springs from the Flipper platform that is used for debugging.

So what I did that solved this problem is to simply go into your Podfile in the ios folder of your react native project and disabling it as I did here by commenting out this line in my Podfile

```
# use_flipper!('Flipper' => '0.75.1', 'Flipper-Folly' => '2.5.3', 'Flipper-RSocket' => '1.3.1')
```

After that, run `pod install` again

Following this, your React Native application will build successfully and can now run as per normal on your simulator.